# QFX3500 RTG Question

Tags: juniper

i have 2x ae interface in my QFX3500 and i want to use ae1 as primary and ae2 as backup and here is my

```
config :
 set protocols rstp interfaces ae1 disable
 set protocols rstp interfaces ae2 disable
 set ethernet-switching-options redundant-trunk-group group rtg1 interface ae1 primary
 set ethernet-switching-options redundant-trunk-group group rtg1 interface ae2
 set redundant-trunk-group group tg1 preempt-cutover-timer 60
```

and here is the output from the RTG :

```
run show redundant-trunk-group
Group      Interface   State       Time of last flap                      Flap
name                                                                      count

rtg1       ae1.0      Up/Pri/Act  Never                                      0
           ae2.0      Up          Never                                      0
```

so my questions are :

1. when I executed "run show interfaces terse" it showed that ae2 was up, it should not be down? also the port-channel in that switch which is connected to ae2 is showing UP.
2. is it safe if I disable rstp for ae1 and ae2?

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [redundant-trunk-group](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/redundant-trunk-groups.html) correctly, yes.  It's normal that both interfaces appear as UP.

It is **required that you disable RSTP** on the RTG interfaces, and the way you've done so is good.  RTG cannot co-exist with xSTP on the same interfaces.  Other ports on the switch can continue to run xSTP though.